# Is it true that Babel doesn't really have to call super() if a class extends Object?

Tags: javascript, babeljs

I noticed [using Babel](https://babeljs.io/), if I transpile

```
class Rectangle {
  a = 1;
}
```

using stage-0, then the resulting code has a constructor function but there is no call to `super()`

But if the code is changed to:

```
class Rectangle extends Object {
  a = 1;
}
```

then the transpiled code is:

```
function _defineProperty(obj, key, value) { if (key in obj) { Object.defineProperty(obj, key, { value: value, enumerable: true, configurable: true, writable: true }); } else { obj[key] = value; } return obj; }

class Rectangle extends Object {
  constructor(...args) {
    super(...args);

    _defineProperty(this, "a", 1);
  }

}
```

Isn't version 1 and 2 of the original code actually the same? (all classes extend Object). And so if version 1 doesn't call `super()`, it looks like the constructor of Object doesn't do anything, so version 2 also has no reason to call it?

Answer (score 4):

> Isn't version 1 and 2 of the original code actually the same? (all classes extend Object).

No, not *quite*. Let's compare:

```
class Base {
}
```

and

```
class Sub extends Object {
}
```

It's true that both `Base.prototype` and `Sub.prototype` use `Object.prototype` as their prototypes, but that doesn't make them the same. Two differences:

1. `Base` (the constructor function) uses `Object` as its prototype; `Sub` uses `Function.prototype`.
2. `Base` will *create* the object when you call it via `new`; `Sub` won't, it expects the superclass constructor (`Object`) to do that. Which means it has to call it. (The constructors are marked to indicate whether they're base or subclass constructors, and the processing of the `new` operator acts according.)

Demonstrating #1 (with an ES2015+ JavaScript engine):

```js
class Base {
}

class Sub extends Object {
}

// Both `prototype` properties inherit from `Object.prototype`
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(Base.prototype) === Object.prototype);

console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(Sub.prototype) === Object.prototype);

// But the constructors themselves inherit from different things
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(Base) === Function.prototype);

console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(Sub) === Object);
```

> And so if version 1 doesn't call `super()`, it looks like the constructor of `Object` doesn't do anything, so version 2 also has no reason to call it?

It has to call it. This fails to compile in native JavaScript (ES2015+):

```js
class Example extends Object {
    constructor() {
        this.foo = "bar";
    }
}
console.log(new Example().foo);
```

If you have an `extends`, you must call `super` in order to create the new object.

My `Sub` at the top of the answer compiles because it doesn't have an explicit constructor so it gets the default subclass constructor (`constructor(...args) { super(...args); }`). But `Example` fails because it has an explicit constructor but doesn't make the `super` call.

Comment: `Base.__proto__ === Function.prototype` is true  and `Sub.__proto__.__proto__ === Function.prototype` is true

Comment: @nopole - Not on a compliant JavaScript implementation it isn't. Run the snippet in the answer. Or using your exact code (although it's best to avoid using `__proto__`): https://jsfiddle.net/a2p1um7y/

Comment: @nopole - Naturally, if you're transpiling down to ES5, then *all* functions have `Function.prototype` as their prototype. But the transpiled code you show in your question still uses `class` syntax, which sets up inheritance between the subclass and base class when you use `extends` (so `static` methods are inherited).

Comment: This is confusing. I think if `class Foo {}` and `class Foo extends Object {}` behaved the same it would have been ideal. `extends null` could have been the explicit opt-in for no Object static inheritance. Why do spec authors like to create discrepancies?

Comment: @trusktr - I think the intent was to make the `Foo` function created by `class Foo {}` and `function Foo {}` as similar as possible. But it's definitely confusing. This is what happens when a language starts out designed in 10 days, within just a few years has millions of lines of code in the wild it has to remain compatible with, spends 10 years effectively stagnating for various reasons, and then has lots of new features added to it while (almost) entirely maintaining backward compatibility. No one would *design* it this way today. :-D

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I actually thought about this again the other day, and the fact that a `class Foo {}` doesn't have `Foo.keys`, `Foo.defineProperty`, etc, _might_ be the only good reason for the behavior, because all those static `Object` methods are more like a whole separate lib that every class doesn't need. Maybe there could have been an alternative feature for that like `class Object { noinherit static keys() {...} }` where a prototype access would return undefined. That's tricky for non-static members though. Then again, `Object.prototype` has a bunch of stuff that isn't blocked.